# Выравнивание изображения по вертикали

Tags: html, css

Добрый день, есть ли способ выровнять изображения по вертикали при том что высота элемента в котором находится изображение не известна

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<p>Текст который может перейти на другую строчку</p>
<img src"Изображение.jpg">
</div>
```

p.s. можно ли сделать так что бы высота не указывалась

p.s.s Хотелось бы сделать так что бы все элементы находящийся в  были вертикально по центру относительно этого

Comment: надо гуглить `display: flex`

Comment: Уточните что именно нужно, выровнять относительно чего, как должен обтекать текст, что вообще ожидается от вёрстки?

Comment: Хотелось бы сделать так что бы все элементы находящийся в <div> были вертикально по центру относительно этого <div>

Comment: Вот вам куча и один способ как центрировать: [Центрирование в CSS: полное руководство](http://frontender.info/centering-css-complete-guide/#tsentrirovanievcsspolnoerukovodstvo)

Answer (score 1):

Выходит как-то так:

```css
.my-flex-container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 my-flex-container">
  <p>Текст который может перейти на другую строчку</p>
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/26b3fa7a4e153dfd24243a20dc0fcf21?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" />
</div>
```

Используется технология `flex`, описание используемых свойств прочитать и посмотреть на их работу можно [тут](http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/).

Comment: А можно ли как нибудь выровнять по вертикали, и при этом не указывая высоту блока в котором находятся элементы?

Comment: Если блоку не задавать высоту, то он будет принимать размеры контента, который будет находиться в нём и выравнивать будет некуда,  потому что контент будет занимать всю высоту блока

Comment: @Новичок, если не указывать, то блок не будет растягиваться по вертикали, т. е. получится что выравнивание по вертикали будет, но толку - ноль, т. к. верхняя и нижняя граница прилипнут к ближайшим элементам соответственно. Итого: можно и не указывать высоту, но толку от выравнивания тогда никакого не будет.